# How do i include a common module in 2 different applications(Android)

Tags: android, makefile, multiple-makefiles

I need a little help with Android makefiles.

There is one common module for 2 of my applications. I planned to have a makefile for common module`common.mk` and include it in both my applications.

Like this:

```
app1:
=====
main.c
Android.mk
  ...
  ...
  include ../common/common.mk
  LOCAL_MODULE := app1
  ...
  ...

app2:
=====
main.c
Android.mk
  ...
  ...
  include ../common/common.mk
  LOCAL_MODULE := app2
  ...
  ...

common:
=======
common.mk
common.c
```

when I build from root directory using `make app2`, I am receiving multiple definition errors for all the functions that are apart of common module.

I came to a conclusion that the common.mk is getting included twice while the Android build system is searching for the right target(app2 in my case). Which is why the problem is occurring.

Now how do I control this? What is the standard way in Android?

Answer (score 1):

A correct way should be to build a *common* library (shared or static) by using the `BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY` or `BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY` targets.

And then to add them into `app1` and `app2` just use the `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` or `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES` to create a dependency between `app1`, `app2` and `common`.

Check the [Android.mk file syntax specification](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/ANDROID-MK.html) for more informations:

> **BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY**
>
> Points to a build script that collects all the information about the module you provided in LOCAL_XXX variables and determines how to build a target shared library from the sources you listed. Note that you must have LOCAL_MODULE and LOCAL_SRC_FILES defined, at a minimum before including this file.
>
> Example usage:
>
> ```
>   include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
> ```
>
> Note that this will generate a file named lib$(LOCAL_MODULE).so
>
> **BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY**
>
> A variant of BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY that is used to build a target static library instead. Static libraries are not copied into your project/packages but can be used to build shared libraries (see LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES and LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES described below).
>
> Example usage:
>
> ```
>   include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
> ```
>
> Note that this will generate a file named lib$(LOCAL_MODULE).a
>
> **LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES**
>
> The list of static libraries modules (built with BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY) that should be linked to this module. This only makes sense in shared library modules.
>
> **LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES**
>
> The list of shared libraries modules this module depends on at runtime. This is necessary at link time and to embed the corresponding information in the generated file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This certainly is a procedure, But i donot want to build the module into library. There are other variables inside common.mk that my apps would use. So library would not suffice my need.

Comment: @Manty Instead of creating library you can *just* include the `common.c` file by doing `LOCAL_SRC_FILES += ../common/common.c` in both of the `Android.mk`.

Comment: My system is little complex. I cannot do that. I need to find a way.

Comment: @Manty So try to wrap the functions define in `common.mk` with some `ifndef` to not redefine them.

Comment: Can i use ifndef in mk files? Sorry i am not aware.

Comment: @Manty `Android.mk` **are** makefiles, so you can use [`ifndef`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Syntax) like in every makefiles.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56691/discussion-between-jml-and-manty).

Answer (score 1):

In common.mk the variable which you are using for assigning C files use := instead of +=.

Whenever common.mk is called it will assign independent value of each module